# WPF command binding works only a few times

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, mvvm-light

I have created a UserControl named `AnswerUserControl`. XAML file looks like this (it's only button):

```xml
<UserControl
    ...>

    <Button
        DataContext="{Binding Path=ViewModel, 
                      RelativeSource={
                          RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                          AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}
                      }}"
        Command="{Binding Path=ClickCommand}"
        Content="{Binding Path=Reply}" />

</UserControl>
```

And `cs` file with dependency property to `AnswerViewModel`:

```cs
public partial class AnswerUserControl : UserControl
{
    public AnswerUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public AnswerViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return (AnswerViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(AnswerViewModel), typeof(AnswerUserControl));
}
```

AnswerViewModel class:

```cs
public class AnswerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string reply;

    public string Reply
    {
        get
        {
            return reply;
        }
        set
        {
            reply = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Reply));
        }
    }

    private ICommand clickCommand;

    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return clickCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            clickCommand = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ClickCommand));
        }
    }

    public AnswerViewModel(Action<int> click, string reply, int index)
    {
        void Click()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"AnswerViewModel click at {index}");
            click(index);
        }

        Reply = reply;
        ClickCommand = new RelayCommand(Click);
    }
}
```

In Window I am adding this UserContol like this:

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <local:AnswerUserControl
        ViewModel="{Binding Path=VMA}" />
</StackPanel>
```

`VMA` is an `AnswerViewModel` in Window's ViewModel:

```cs
private AnswerViewModel vma;

public AnswerViewModel VMA
{
    get
    {
        return vma;
    }
    set
    {
        vma = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(VMA));
    }
}

static int number = 1;

public HomeViewModel()
{
    VMA = new AnswerViewModel(x => { Console.WriteLine($"Click Number: {number++}"); }, "Reply", 0);
}
```

The problem I am facing is that ClickCommand is executed only a few times. When I click slowly on the button it is executed from 4 to 6 times and when I click fast it is executed over 20 times and then it stops working. Where I am making a mistake?

Comment: does the breakpoint still hit on click function when not working ?

Comment: No, I set a breakpoint, and the function wasn't executed. It looks like binding just stop working

Comment: Why use a dependency property as the usercontrol can have a datacontext set? It feels like extra steps

Comment: @M.B. I haven't known about this because WPF and C# it's not my main language, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a crude version of how it can be implemented. For the mainwindow we can use the following code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowDataContext();
    }
}
```

As seen above we assign a viewmodel to the mainwindow, in this viewmodel we can define a datacontext for the usercontrol. Giving us the following code;

```
public class MainWindowDataContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowDataContext()
    {
        newDatacontext = new DataContextTest();

    }
    private DataContextTest _newDatacontext;

    public DataContextTest newDatacontext
    {
        get => _newDatacontext;
        set
        {
            if(_newDatacontext == value)
                return;
            _newDatacontext = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(newDatacontext));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Do not mind the interface or the getter/setter, this is purely for demonstrating how binding can be notified that a property has changed.

Within the MainWindowDataContext we create a DataContextTest class. This viewmodel/datacontext class holds our command and can hold other bindings for the usercontrol.

```
public class DataContextTest
{
    public ICommand ButtonCommand => new RelayCommand(executeThis);


    private void executeThis()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"VM clicked ");
    }
}
```

For the front side where the xaml code and bindings reside I wrote the following things;
A usercontrol that has a button, and in the mainwindow I inserted the usercontrol.

```
<Window x:Class="Tryout.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tryout"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1 DataContext="{Binding newDatacontext,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></local:UserControl1>
</Grid>
```

The mainwindow uses the MainWindowDataContext, this is being assigned in the constructor (see code block 1). The MainWindowDataContext has a getter setter for the usercontrol that needs a datacontext. The userControl gets notified when the datacontext changes.

When looking at the usercontrol xaml we see the following

```
<UserControl x:Class="Tryout.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tryout"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <Button Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" Width="200" Height="100" Content="test"/>
</Grid>
```

With all this code it resolves to the following hierarchy for the viewmodels.

MainWindow -> MainWindowDataContext -> DataContextTest.

Because the MainWindow uses the UserControl we need to define a viewmodel for the MainWindow. Once that is set you can assign a datacontext/viewmodel to the usercontrol through binding on the front end.

No need for Dependecy Properties, a datacontext would suffice in most of the cases (: